# Reduce row retrieval time from big SQLAlchemy database

Tags: python, database, performance, sqlalchemy, pyramid

In my Pyramid application I have `models.py`:

```
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
Base = declarative_base()

followers = Table('followers',
                  Base.metadata,
                  Column('follower_id', Integer, ForeignKey('artist.id')),
                  Column('followed_id', Integer, ForeignKey('artist.id')))

class Artist(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'artist'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Text)

    followed = relationship('Artist',
                                   secondary=followers,
                                   primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
                                   secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == id),
                                   backref=backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'),
                                   lazy='dynamic')

Index('my_index', Artist.id, unique=True, mysql_length=255)
```

My `artist` table has 85,632 rows and `followers` auxiliary table has 420,749 rows.

Currently if I try to retrieve `followed` of some `artist` like this:

```
db.query(Artist).first().folowed.all()
```

The query takes around 30-40 ms to retrieve the rows, how could I improve my model to reduce this time?

By the way my `Artist` model is based on this [tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-viii-followers-contacts-and-friends/page/3).

Comment: Try to use InnoDB, that way ForeignKeys are handled by the database, not by SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I added `__table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}` to my `class Artist` model. Do I have to upgrade my db?

Comment: Try adding an index on `followers.follower_id`.

Comment: I added both suggestions and time dropped to around 2ms per query, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

- Use [InnoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB), that way ForeignKeys are handled by the database, not by SQLAlchemy.
- index the field `followers.follower_id`.